# What is the equivalent covariance matrix to the variance in the 1D case?

Tags: python, numpy, gaussian

I am trying to generate a three-dimensional multivariate normal distribution whose values will range from approximately 0 to 100 in each dimension.

When I generate a 1D normal distribution with mean 50 and variance 16:

```
data = random.normal(50, 16, 1000)
```

the resulting distribution has values range from approximately 0 to 100. But when I extend that to the multivariate case, the values only range from 35 to 65:

```
covar = [[16, 0, 0], [0, 16, 0], [0, 0, 16]]
data = random.multivariate_normal([50, 50, 50], covar, 1000)
```

When using `random.normal` for three dimensions I get the expected result, values ranging from 0 to 100.

```
data = random.normal(50, 16, size=(3,1000))
```

Where does this discrepancy come from? In order to get the range of values I want in each dimension in the multivariate case I have to make the covariance matrix like this:

```
covar = [[300, 0, 0], [0, 300, 0], [0, 0, 300]]
```

which seems completely unreasonable for a normal distribution with mean 50.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the variance with the standard deviation.

The `scale=` parameter to `np.random.normal` specifies the *standard deviation* (i.e. the square root of the variance), whereas the diagonal of the covariance matrix you pass to `np.random.multivariate_normal` corresponds to the *variances* in each dimension.

Try setting the diagonal of your covariance matrix to `16**2 == 256`.

Comment: This makes sense now! I thought that `np.random.multivariate_normal` also uses standard deviation but clearly not. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you mean "(i.e. the square root of the variance)" instead of "(i.e. the square of the variance)"

Comment: @ayhan Yes, I accidentally a word there :-)